# Investment options for remote money in US

Tags: united-states, investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies, russia

I live and work in Russia normally but recently I've been to United States of America, doing work for my employer. I was paid in US dollars and money was transferred to my US bank account. I've returned to Russia, but I have around $2000 left in my bank account in US.

I don't have any use for them now, but potentially I can:

- Use them as a tourist in country with dollars currency
- Convert them to Russian ruble
- Order something from US store and pay

But as I don't have any use for them now - I am seeking for opportunities to invest them, so they don't just lay around. I am not good at stock market or any other schemes, requiring attention and domain knowledge. And don't feel like I would like to start digging any time soon.

**What are the safe and sweat-free options I have to invest money remotely?**

Comment: look into bitcoin.

Comment: Transfer to Russian bank, most probably to dollar account in Russian bank. After that, invest them here. IIRC, having an account in a foreign bank requires you to file a lot of forms with Russian government.

Comment: This seems like two different questions - the title makes it sound like you want to know how to "invest" remotely, but the question makes it clear that you have no idea what to try to invest it in in the first place and are "seeking opportunities" which are NOT standard securities (stocks). If the question is "what do I invest in", please clarify. If the question is not "what do I invest in" but is "how do I invest in N while remote", please specify what N is so that you'll get better answers.